# Additon on list in python

Tags: python

i am writing a program that calculates time spent watching movies, but i have gotten into a problem. I don't know how to add all the numbers together, below is some sample minutes from my code that i want to add all together but i dont know how. To specifiy how i want them together i want the code to do x+y+z.

this is all my code that gets the minutes:

```
def convert(lst):
    return ' '.join(lst)

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    test = convert(lines)
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', lines)

# scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    # print titles only
    minute = soup.find("p", class_="text-link text-footer")
    tid = minute.get_text()
    tid2 = tid.strip()
    tid3 = [(tid2[:3])]
```

some sample minutes from my code that i get if i do print(tid3):

```
148
119
121
120
113
129
```

i have tried:

```
print(sum(map(int, tid3)))
print(sum(tid3))
```

the code print(sum(map(int, tid3))) just print outs 1+4+8 instead of 148+119

the code print(sum(tid3)) just gets error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str

Comment: What did these do ? What is the problem ? Do you have any errors ? How do you fill tid3 ?

Comment: Update your question with more of your code.

Comment: What does print(tid2) gives ?

Comment: @azro print(tid2) gives: 148 mins  
    
     More details at
     IMDb
TMDb
Report this film

Comment: only ? Where the other values ? Do you have a loop to get all the different number ? Please share all the code related, we won't ask you for more a dozen times ;)

Comment: @azro, i know updated with all the code i have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you were trying to sum at each iteration, at this moment you have access to only one value, you have to collect them all (in a `list` as `int`) along the for-loop, and sum at the end :

```
values = []
for url in urls:
    # ...
    tid2 = tid.strip()  # 148 mins More details at IMDb TMDb Report this film
    value = int(tid2[:3])  # 148 as int
    values.append(value)

total = sum(values)
print(total)
```

And you can remove the intermetiate `tid*` variable, and just do

```
for url in urls:
    # ...
    minute = soup.find("p", class_="text-link text-footer")
    values.append(int(minute.get_text().strip()[:3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# you can create your function here 
def sum_digit(num):
      result = 0
      while num > 0:
        rem = num % 10
        result = result + rem
        num = int(num/10)
      return result

def convert(lst):
    return ' '.join(lst)

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    test = convert(lines)
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', lines)

# scrape elements
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    # print titles only
    minute = soup.find("p", class_="text-link text-footer")
    tid = minute.get_text()
    tid2 = tid.strip()
    tid3 = [(tid2[:3])] # then can call here `sum_degit(num)`
```

Comment: The OP already post this code, and it was not concluant, so maybe we should wait to get more details